# Evans' PDE: proof of theorem 4, chapter 5.9

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

I am self-reading Evan's PDE. In the proof of Theorem 4, Chapter 5.9 (page 304-305, 2nd edition), it says that (which I paraphrase):

> Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a bounded open subset, and let $\partial U$ be smooth. Assume that $u \in L^2(0,T; H^2(U))$ and $u' \in L^2(0,T; L^2(U))$. Choose a bounded open set $V$ such that $U$ is relatively compact in $V$. Then we could do an extension $\bar{u} := Eu$. Then $\bar{u}' \in L^2(0,T; L^2(V))$, with the estimate $$\| \bar{u}' \|_{L^2(0,T; L^2(V))} \leq C_{T,U} \|u'\|_{L^2(0,T; L^2(U))},$$
> this follows if we consider difference quotients in $t$-variable, and observe also that $E$ is a bounded linear operator.

But I really don't see how it follows. For the extension operator, if we have $E(u') = (Eu)' = \bar{u}'$, then we have $\|\bar{u}'\|_{L^2(V)} \leq \|u'\|_{L^2(U)}$. Integrating with respect to $t$ from $0$ to $T$ yields the desired result. But I am not sure whether $E(u') = (Eu)' = \bar{u}'$ is true. And I don't know how to use the difference quotient. Could anyone give me some hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can compute for all $\phi \in C_c^\infty(0,T)$
$$\begin{aligned} ((Eu)',\phi)_{L^2(0,T)}=-(Eu,\phi')_{L^2(0,T)}&=-\left(Eu,\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\phi(t+h)-\phi(t)}{h}\right)_{L^2(0,T)} \\ &=\left(\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{Eu(t)-Eu(t-h)}{h},\phi\right)_{L^2(0,T)} \end{aligned}$$

Comment: Thank you! Just to check my understanding: here do we use duality to show $\|(Eu)'\|_{L^2} = \sup_{\|\phi\|_{L^2}=1} ((Eu)', \phi)_{L^2}$? For the last step, I think we want to use $\|D^h u\|_{L^2(0,T)} \leq C \|u\|_{L^2(0,T)}$; but here do we have any restriction on the domain? As on page 292, Chapter 5.8.2, Theorem 3 says such estimate works for $D^h u$ on a smaller domain. I guess we don't need to care about this since we are passing $h \to 0$, but how to make it rigorous?